# Merge 2 XML files where file2 elements overwrite file1 elements only if those file2 elements exist

Tags: c#, xml, merge

I've looked and searched to find solution but only found examples of direct merge.
My task is as follows...
File1 is my "master" config file and I deserialize it with a c# class template.  My example is just a snippet, it's a lot larger.
File2 is a file that contains a subset of the same settings (same class) that are used only in specific cases.
I'd like to deserialize both and overwrite only those settings in File1 that exist in File2.
By the way, I don't even need to save this file to disk, it's be nice to just update File1 deserialized `configuration` object.
Thank you!

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("DiagsConfig.xml"))
    configuration = (Configuration)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
```

**File1:**

```
<Configuration>
    <PathDataOutput>D:\Diagnostics Data</PathDataOutput>
    <FRUTestTool>
        <NumDirectoriesToKeep>5</NumDirectoriesToKeep>
        <ControllerTest>
            <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
            <Photocells>
                <NumPolls>20</NumPolls>
            </Photocells>
        </ControllerTest>
    </FRUTestTool>
</Configuration>
```

**File2:**

```
<Configuration>
    <FRUTestTool>
        <ControllerTest>
            <Photocells>
                <NumPolls>200000000000000</NumPolls>
            </Photocells>
        </ControllerTest>
    </FRUTestTool>
</Configuration>
```

**Combined:** (as you can see, only diff. is `NumPolls` that was carried over from File2)

```
<Configuration>
    <PathDataOutput>D:\Diagnostics Data</PathDataOutput>
    <FRUTestTool>
        <NumDirectoriesToKeep>5</NumDirectoriesToKeep>
        <ControllerTest>
            <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
            <Photocells>
                <NumPolls>200000000000000</NumPolls>
            </Photocells>
        </ControllerTest>
    </FRUTestTool>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What are your classes?  The only way of doing this is enumerating through the classes recursively.  You need to deserialize both files and then compare properties in each class as you recursively go through each child class.

Comment: Just the typical C# class structure... ```public class Configuration
        {
            public string PathDataOutput;
            public FRUTestTool FRUTestTool;
        }```  I was hoping to keep this generic so that I don't have to revisit the enumerating code.  And how would I check if something doesn't exist in File2?  I'd have to make all my variables nullable.  Thanks!

Comment: XML serialization requires class to be the same as the xml structure. To be generic you have to manually parse using XDocument  which is xml linq (or XmlDocument or XMLReader).

Comment: The structure is the same for both files (same class).  But File2 does not have all the elements, which if deserlaized automatically sets them to defaults.  That's one of the problems I don't know how to get around... I could make all values null-able but it's not what I want to do for various reasons (one of which is that some already are).

Comment: My issue is there is no way of joining the two files.  You would need a unique ID to join and there isn't an ID in both files.